# Error: Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed. How do I go about this?

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers

So I have been stuck on this problem of sharing a function from one class to another and every solution I have found so far as not solved my problem.
One instance is here(I assure you there are others), [http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cdiag436]

Bar.h

```
#ifndef __Bar_h_
#define __Bar_h_
#include "BaseApplication.h"  
#include <Foo.h>  

class Foo;  
Foo *foo;  

class Bar : BaseApplication
{
   public:
Bar(void);
~Bar(void);
   protected:
virtual void barCreate(void);
};
#endif
```

Bar.cpp

```
#include "Bar.h"
#include <Foo.h>
Bar::Bar(void){}
Bar::~Bar(void){}
void Bar::barCreate(void)
{
     if(foo->foobar()==true) //error: pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed
        {//stuff}
}
```

Foo.h

```
#ifndef __foo_h_
#define __foo_h_
class Foo
{
public:
Foo(void);
~Foo(void);
bool foobar(void);
};
#endif
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"
Foo::Foo(void){}
bool Foo::foobar(void){ return true; }
```

If I could get some pointers or explanation of where i'm going wrong that would be great.

Comment: Remove `#include <Foo.h>` from `Bar.h` - you have forward declaration.

Comment: Are you really missing the semicolon from the `Foo` definition, or is it just copy-paste error here?

Comment: And don't use names with leading (especially two) underscore(s)

Comment: In addition to what Kiril mentions, why do you need the `Class Foo;` forward declaration and the `Foo *foo` pointer in Bar.h? You can probably remove those, too. The classes should be defined with class, not Class.

Comment: @Brady - you're actually right, I didn't see that there's no `Foo*` in `Bar.h`.

Comment: You don't need to do `#ifndef __foo_h_` in header files, use `#pragma once` instead. It's better because it doesn't even open the file for reading if it's already been opened once.

Comment: @MarkIngram: that pragma isn't portable.

Comment: @MarkIngram: `#pragma once` is not part of the Standard.  Moreover, some (older) compilers didn't implement it properly.  I believe the common advice these days is to use macro guards because they always work.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  This is compiling for me under VC10.

Comment: @honk It's fairly portable - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability - I'd be interested to know what compiler OP is using if it's not on the list...

Comment: @MarkIngram: That page lists e.g. GCC supporting it as of 4.6. I regularly need to work with gcc-4.3.2 under a not so old SL installation, so I would be careful with recommending it.

Comment: Fair enough, although gcc-4.3.2 is over 4 years old!

Comment: @MarkIngram More generally: `#pragma once` wasn't adopted because it can't be implemented reliably if there are networked drives (the case in all of the places I've worked).  Include guards are the standard and the preferred way of avoiding multiple includes.  (And most of the compilers I've used aren't on the list on the page you quote.)  If you want to use `#pragma once`, it should be in addition to, and not instead of include guards.

Comment: @JohnDibling I'm using VC10 aswell.

Comment: @JamesKanze so should I not be using '#pragma once' then.

Comment: @user1741215 It depends.  If Windows is a major platform, then you might want to consider it.  (Most other platforms will ignore it, so it won't do any real harm.)  In addition to the include guards, however, and not instead of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misreading the error. It is not complaining about having a pointer to an incomplete type, but about *dereferencing* it.

```
if(foo->foobar()==true)
```

At this point the type of `foo` is an incomplete type, so the compiler cannot check whether it will have a `foobar` member function (or member functor).

Basically for an incomplete type you can declare and define pointers or references, declare interfaces (functions that take or return the type). But other than that you cannot create objects of the type, or *use* the pointers/references for anything other than copying the pointer/reference.

Regarding what you are doing wrong, you need to look to your real files in more details. Either you are not including the header that defines `Foo`, or you have multiple `Foo` types (different namespaces? one defines the type, another has the forward declaration) or your include guards are wrong and even if you include the header the guard discards the contents of the header. Note that after inclusion of the header that defines `Foo` you don't need to (and should not) provide a forward declaration of the type, as that can easily lead to *multiple* declarations of `Foo` in different contexts. If removing the forward declaration fails to compile, figure out why and fix that.

Comment: Okay so after I got rid of the forward declaration of 'Foo' and checked to make sure the header guards were correct I now get a "error: identifier "Foo" is undefined", while declaring the pointer.

Comment: @user1741215: Some things that can cause the `Foo` identifier not appearing: it is in a different namespace, the header has not been included, or it has been included but the include guards are wrong and the precompiler did not see the definition. I would start by checking the namespace, after that, tell the compiler to only do preprocessing and check the generated file to see if the appropriate file has been included, and if the definition is present (and where).

Comment: I really appreciate checking the namespace seems to have now solved the problem. I would like to give you a *up* thing but my reputation isn't high enough. Nonetheless, thank you sincerely for the help with this problem.

Comment: @user1741215: I don't think you need rep to upvote or to accept answers.

Comment: well it turns out I actually do to upvote (at least 15) but I can accept it.

Comment: The trick here is "different namespaces"... I hadn't realized my forward declaration was in one, since the file was so long and written by someone else.